# How to fix an error Plone RelStorage using AWS RDS Read replica by psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, plone, relstorage

We want to use AWS RDS Read replica by psycopg2, but we got an error.

Our env:

- Plone 5
- RelStorage 1.6.3
- psycopg2 2.7.3.2
- AWS RDS PostgreSQL (Read Replica)
- buildout.conf: `rel-storage = read-only true`

Error:

`psycopg2.NotSupportedError: cannot use serializable mode in a hot standby
HINT:  You can use REPEATABLE READ instead.`

We set:

`default_transaction_isolation  repeatable read`

How can I do anything?

Comment: Manabu, you really will get more people seeing your questions if you post them to our forum... Happy new year!